# How to replace JSDOM with cheerio for Readability

Tags: node.js, cheerio, jsdom

I'd like to use [Readability](https://github.com/mozilla/readability) to parse out the "article" content within web pages. `Readability` does a good job, but it depends on [JSDOM](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) which seems to be very slow and throws errors if parsing CSS content fails (which I do not need at all), but it's not possible to ignore CSS in `JSDOM`, as I understand from the Gibhub issues of the project.

I've been trying to replace JSDOM with [cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/), but I haven't been able to figure out what part of its API is compatible with the output of `JSDOM`.

In `JSDOM`, the statement

```
var doc = new JSDOM(html);
```

produces a DOM object which can be passed into

```
let reader = new Readability(doc.window.document);
```

In `cheerio` however, there doesn't seem to anything that produces a DOM object.
I've tried

```
var $ = cheerio.load(html);
var object_something = $('html');
```

It throws an error when I call `new Readability(object_something)`

```
Error: First argument to Readability constructor should be a document object.
```

which clearly means that what it says. `object_something` is an object, but not sure what it actually is.

Is it even possible to produce a DOM object with `cheerio`? I have over 10 million local HTML documents, so any performance improvement would save me a lot of time.